# webpack-dev-server hot loading not working with boot2docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am currently trying to get `webpack-dev-server` working with [hot loading](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#hot-mode), through boot2docker.

I have files changes being picked up correctly in my container, by using `docker-osx-dev`, but the socket.io hot reloading is not working.

The reason being that I set `--host 0.0.0.0` when running the server, so that it would be accesible on my host machine. This meant, however, that it is looking for the socket.io server at `0.0.0.0`.

So when I load the page, it tries to connect to `http://0.0.0.0:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1434584701670-0` and I get an error in my consul. In reality it should be connecting to `http://dockerhost:8080/socket.io/`.

Is there anyway to tell `webpack-dev-server` to use a different host to get the socket.io connection?

[The Github issue 63](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/163) may refer to the same problem, but is unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

So I realized that even though it was giving me an error in the console, by trying to connect to the wrong host, it was also connecting to the right host so hot loading did work.

In the end, my config looked something like this:

```
var entry = ["./config/mainApp"];
var loaders = {
    "jsx": ["react-hot", "babel-loader?stage=0"]
    "js": {
        loader: "babel-loader?stage=0",
        include: path.join(__dirname, "app")
    },
    "json": "json-loader",
    "json5": "json5-loader",
    "txt": "raw-loader",
    "png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg": "url-loader?limit=10000",
    "woff|woff2": "url-loader?limit=100000",
    "ttf|eot": "file-loader",
    "wav|mp3": "file-loader",
    "html": "html-loader",
    "md|markdown": ["html-loader", "markdown-loader"],
    "css": "style-loader!css-loader"
};
var preloaders = {
    "js": "source-map-loader"
};
var plugins = [
    new webpack.PrefetchPlugin("react"),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: true,
        template: "app/index.html"
    }),
    new webpack.PrefetchPlugin("react/lib/ReactComponentBrowserEnvironment")
];
module.exports = {
    entry: entry,
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        sourceMapFilename: "bundle.map",
        pathinfo: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: loadersByExtension(loaders),
        preloaders: loadersByExtension(preloaders)
    },
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    debug: true,
    resolve: {
        root: path.join(__dirname, "app"),
        extensions: ["", ".web.js", ".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        inline: true
    }
};
```

and I started it like this:

```
webpack-dev-server --config webpack-hot-dev-server.config.js --colors --progress --hot
```

For a full example, [check out my the initial stages of my app that just has this boilerplate + react](https://github.com/lucibus/lucibus/tree/92690db8f63eaac32e79bba59382a6adc6eb60c2)

Comment: is this above boilerplate available anywhere? I just get a 404 and would love to get hot reload working with docker

Comment: @Joshua Sorry about that, just fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

I [switched](https://github.com/rnsloan/webpackdev-server-boot2docker) to using https://github.com/brikis98/docker-osx-dev which uses rsync to sync files between OS X and the container and also adds a hosts entry for `http://dockerhost` that allowed socket.io to poll the container correctly from the OS X web browser.

Answer (score 1):

After some hours of searching i have [found](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/bin/webpack-dev-server.js#L117-L131), that inline option just adds entry point. You can fix this error by replacing options.host (which is 0.0.0.0 in your case) with localhost, or some other host.

The easiest way to detect file changes is to set [watchOptions.poll](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#watchoptions-poll) to true.

Answer (score 0):

After some head scratching here is the solution:

1- Add a hostname to **/etc/hosts**

```
YOUR_DOCKER_MACHINE_IP    devapp (or any other hostname you choose)
```

2- In your webpackconfig entry

```
entry: 
    main: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://devapp:YOUR_EXPOSED_PORT',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        YOUR_SCRIPT_FILE
    ]
}
```